# starting tomcat v8.0 server at localhost has encountered p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m . Failed to start

Tags: java, maven, tomcat8

I tried with the available solutions for this exception.

I cleared entire my local repository, did `maven update` also but still getting the this error.
I checked the versions of `JRE` and `tomcat java versions` both are same.

stack trace as follows:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/lrmedge]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/lrmedge]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
... 6 more
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@20a9ef5e]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5059)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 6 more
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@3d16c539]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:699)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 9 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
... 12 more
 Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
... 13 more

 Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
 SEVERE: A child container failed during start
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:915)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 6 more

Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:787)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:923)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 11 more

Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

  Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
  INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
  Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
  INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
  Oct 12, 2016 5:07:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
  SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:316)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:492)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:821)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:534)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: it will be helpful if you share your pom.xml.

Comment: Due to company restrictions, I can't share my pom file...
What are the possible ways to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the jar files which were corrupted... I just tried to unzip jar files manually, then I found some jar files were corrupted & they are not able to unzip.. this is the reason why I got these `exceptions`